# Cannot add Web Reference

Tags: webservices, gack

Recently we came across an issue with adding web references to existing c# project. Basically we tried to give the URL which was the generated enterprise wsdl as a web reference to our solution. And we tried it on our fsandbox environment. Here is the issue I'm getting,

"An internal server error has occurred An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting, any error id shown on this page as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience. Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com! Error ID: 1349832752-5469 (39318494)"

We have been using this feature with great success for last couple of years. But this is the first it is giving a weird error message like this. Please help to sort this out

Thanks,
Mudi

Comment: This doesn't provide technical detail. So, you will have to contact Salesforce with given error id.

Comment: What API method were you calling when the error occured?

Answer (score 0):

I connected with SFDC support. And they were unable to fix the issue. Instead they suggested to use Add Service Reference instead of Add Web Reference.

But when I tried to load the web Reference today, it worked well as expected. So not sure what's going on here. Either way it works fine now