# Cannot Set LoginResult.serverUrl - UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService

Tags: webservices, .net, service

I've been successfully using integrations to the SFDC using c# solution. So far I added the web reference and used it without any issues. But then I started add the Service Refference, by downloading the enteprise wsdl to local and used by Add Service Reference option. And I was reffering to following article (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet.meta/salesforce_developer_environment_dotnet_tipsheet/salesforce_developer_environment_verify_dotnet_wsdl.htm).
I was able to run the login function, but there I was unable set the serverUrl as I was unable to find the Url property on my SoalpClient. I think Becaues of that when it tries to SOQL query, it retuns following Error message. 
"UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService"

So when I was using web reference I was successfully able to create the sforcebinding and set the ServerUrl to the property I have in sforcebinding. Really Appriciate Your Help Here

Here is my code,

```
using SFServices.SFDC_FSb_9_23;

namespace SFServices
{
    class SFServiceClient
    {               
        private static SoapClient SFDC_FSb_9_23Binding;
        private static LoginResult CurrentLoginResult;   

        private bool SFLogin()
        {
            SFDC_FSb_9_23Binding = new SoapClient();  

            string UserName = "usename@domain.com.fsandbox";
            string Password = "passwordwithtoken";        

            try
            {
                CurrentLoginResult = SFDC_FSb_9_23Binding.login(null, UserName, Password);   
            }
            catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Login Error: Please contact Technical Team for more details - "+ex);
                //return false;
            }
            if (CurrentLoginResult.passwordExpired)
            {
                throw new Exception("Password Expired: Please contact Technical Team for more details");
                //return false;
            }
            else
            {    

                //HOW CAN I SET THE ServerUrl. AND I THINK THE ISSUE IS HERE

                return true;                
            }
        }


public bool sampleMethod(string field)
        {
            try
            {           
                if (SFLogin())
                {                    
                    String Query_1 = "SELECT Name, Id, FROM ACCOUNT WHERE custom_field__c='" + field + "'";
                    QueryResult qr = new QueryResult();                    
                    SFDC_FSb_9_23Binding.query(null, null, null, null, Query_1, out qr); // ISSUE COMES FROM HERE
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks,
Mudi

Comment: why not use web reference instead of service reference? using service reference has different implementation and is not aligned with documentation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the update. Simply because I encountered an issue when I add the web reference. So after I check with salesforce support, they suggest me to use the service reference.
This is the issue i had previously,
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92781/cannot-add-web-reference

Thanks,
Mudi

Comment: i can add web service without problem to my c# project without problem

Comment: How would you set the serverurl? can you share the code snippet?

Comment: i've added it as web service so the good 'ol, documentation aligned approach works, i.e. 



            `sforce.SforceService binding=new sforce.SforceService();`
            `binding.Url="https://test.salesforce.com";`
            `sforce.LoginResult lr=binding.login("username@emailformat.com", "passwrd+token");`
            `binding.Url=lr.serverUrl;`
            `binding.SessionHeaderValue=new sforce.SessionHeader();`
`binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId;`

Comment: sforce.SforceService binding=new sforce.SforceService();

Considering above, I just tried to replicate the same,
SFServices.SFDC_FSb_9_23 binding = new SFServices.SFDC_FSb_9_23();

But it doesn't allow me to do so, it says
"SFServices.SFDC_FSb_9_23 is a 'namespace' but is used like a type ".
Any suggestions?

Comment: that's because you added it as "Service Reference". you need to add it as "Web Reference"

Comment: Thanks, Where i can find proper code samples that uses Service Reference? Thanks for the the help thus far though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        //LOGIN PART
        sforce.SoapClient sc = new sforce.SoapClient();
        sc.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/34.0");
        sforce.LoginResult lr = sc.login(null, null, "someusername@emailformat.com", "test12345");

        //TRANSACTION PART
        sc = new sforce.SoapClient(); //THIS IS IMPORTANT!!! you can't use the existing instance for some reason...
        sc.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(lr.serverUrl);
        sforce.SessionHeader sh = new sforce.SessionHeader();
        sh.sessionId = lr.sessionId;
        sforce.QueryResult qr;
        sc.queryAll (sh, null, null, "select id, casenumber, subject from Case limit 100", out qr);
```

Take note that we needed another `sc = new sforce.SoapClient();` because utilizing the existing instance used for `login()` was causing the error you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for the Answer. I tried it out and worked pretty well. I just wanted to try this out with Enterprise wsdl, and hence had to change the EndpointAddress to,
"https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/34.0")

Thank you so much for your help once agian